# Merge all of file 2 against file 1 where columns match

Tags: linux, awk, merge

I have the following piece of code in sas that Id like to replicate using bash or python- anything on a linux machine.
It merges two files together (amer_chr and map) based on a matching column (amer_chr.chr=map.chr) but keeping the rows in both files

```
proc sql;
  create table both_amer_chr. as 
    select amer_chr.* , map.* 
    from amer_chr,map 
    where amer_chr.chr=map.chr
  ;
```

Amer_chr looks like

```
chr score weight
1 1 1235
1 2 1268
1 3 1258
2 1 1267
2 1 2467
3 1 1122
3 4 5634
39 3 1234
```

map looks like

```
chr snp pos
1 1_123 1234
1 1_213 1456
1 1_435 1678
2 2_122 1763
2 2_321 1987
2 2_379 2003
3 3_013 2000
3 3_184 2008
3 3_398 4929
3 3_518 6512
```

The resulting both_amer_chr in sas would look like below and wouldnt include the last row of amer_chr due to its chr=39 which is not in file 2

```
chr score weight chr snp pos
    1 1 1235 1 1_123 1234
    1 1 1235 11 1_213 1456
    1 1 1235 1 1_435 1678
    1 2 1268 1 1_123 1234
    1 2 1268 1 1_213 1456
    1 2 1268 1 1_435 1678
    1 3 1258 1 1_123 1234
    1 3 1258 1 1_213 1456
    1 3 1258 1 1_435 1678
    2 1 1267 2 2_122 1763
    2 1 1267 2 2_321 1987
    2 1 1267 2 2_379 2003
    2 1 2467 2 2_122 1763
    2 1 2467 2 2_321 1987
    2 1 2467 2 2_379 2003
    3 1 1122 3 3_013 2000
    3 1 1122 3 3_184 2008
    3 1 1122 3 3_398 4929
    3 1 1122 3 3_518 6512
    3 4 5634 3 3_013 2000
    3 4 5634 3 3_184 2008
    3 4 5634 3 3_398 4929
    3 4 5634 3 3_518 6512
```

essentially joining all of file 2 where the chr column matches to file 1. Is there a way to recreate this using bash maybe with awk, or with python or perl?

Comment: Using bash would be extremely slow and hard to write the code robustly since manipulating text is not what shells were designed to do, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: You should include at least 1 line in the first file that doesn't exist in the 2nd file and vice-versa so we can see how you want those handled.

Comment: I see you added a line to the 1st file with a `chr` value that doesn't appear in the 2nd file, but you didn't add a line to the 2nd file that doesn't appear in the 1st file. [edit] your question to add such a line or state if that cannot occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do (depending on how you want to handle a line in `map` with a `chr` value that doesn't exist in `Amer_chr`), using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and regardless of the order of the lines in the input files and regardless of how many fields exist in the input files:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    vals[$1,++cnt[$1]] = $0
    next
}
$1 in cnt {
    for (i=1; i<=cnt[$1]; i++) {
        print $0, vals[$1,i]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk map Amer_chr
chr score weight chr snp pos
1 1 1235 1 1_123 1234
1 1 1235 1 1_213 1456
1 1 1235 1 1_435 1678
1 2 1268 1 1_123 1234
1 2 1268 1 1_213 1456
1 2 1268 1 1_435 1678
1 3 1258 1 1_123 1234
1 3 1258 1 1_213 1456
1 3 1258 1 1_435 1678
2 1 1267 2 2_122 1763
2 1 1267 2 2_321 1987
2 1 1267 2 2_379 2003
2 1 2467 2 2_122 1763
2 1 2467 2 2_321 1987
2 1 2467 2 2_379 2003
3 1 1122 3 3_013 2000
3 1 1122 3 3_184 2008
3 1 1122 3 3_398 4929
3 1 1122 3 3_518 6512
3 4 5634 3 3_013 2000
3 4 5634 3 3_184 2008
3 4 5634 3 3_398 4929
3 4 5634 3 3_518 6512
```

Answer (score 2):

With `join`, basically

=> Join on first column for the files

```sh
join amer_chr map
```

or for do not default column (-j)

```sh
join -j 1 amer_chr map
```

If you want two columns `chr`

=> Add the format option (-o) for choising columns order

```sh
join -j 1 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3 amer_chr map
```

If you want the data in file `amer_chr` but not in `map`

=> Add append (-a) option and empty text (-e) option

```sh
join -j 1 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3 -a 1 -e "none" amer_chr map
```

If you want the data in file `map` but not in `amer_chr`

=> Add append (-a) option and empty text (-e) option but with the second file

```sh
join -j 1 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3 -a 2 -e "none" amer_chr map
```

If you want the data in file `amer_chr` but not in `map` or in file `map` but not in `amer_chr`

=> Add append (-a) option twice and empty text (-e) option

```sh
join -j 1 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3 -a 1 -a 2 -e "none" amer_chr map
```

Comment: I always want to use `join` but then get frustrated because a) the input has to be sorted (doesn't seem to be a problem in this case) and b) there's no simple way to just say "print all the fields from both files" and so you end up having to list and hard-code specific, sometimes lengthy, field numbers (clearly is a problem in this case). You could do `join amer_chr <(awk '{print $1, $0}' map)` to workaround issue "b" for this and of course `join <(sort amer_chr) <(awk '{print $1, $0}' map | sort)` if "a" is also an issue.

Comment: Yes Ed, I usually use `join` with `sort` for the two files like this `join ...options... <(sort ...options... file1) <(sort ...options... file1)`. I use also the same syntax with `diff` command